# Calculate with java?

Tags: java

I don't know the right name in english when you want to calculate a number with a upper small number besides. Like 1,5 with a small 3 besides (the calculation of 1,5 * 1,5 * 1,5)

Is there a simple and uncomplicated way to do this in java? I want to calculate the volume. I hope you understand my question.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The term is called "power" or "exponent". In Java you can do it as:

```
Math.pow(1.5,3);
```

Answer (score 3):

I think the word you want is "exponent".  Math.pow(a,b) = a^b, so for example Math.pow(1.5,3) = 1.5 * 1.5 * 1.5.  Good luck.

Comment: +1: However don't try `a^b` in Java because it does something else.

Comment: Good point Peter!  a^b written in code does xor bit manipulation.